# how to replace placeholder with image in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext, html-to-pdf

I am working on creating a pdf from html template file where i defined placeholders. i am able to replace the place holders with some text like

content.Replace(["Product_ID"],TextBox1.text);

is there any way i can also replace a placeholder with a checkbox(with either checked or unchecked depending on a condition) ?

Answer (score 0):

Create two images, one for the checkbox "checked" state, and "unchecked", and use an IF statement to get the right image: i.e:

```
string pdfpath = Server.MapPath("PDFs");
string imagepath = Server.MapPath("Images");
Document doc = new Document();
try
{
  PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(pdfpath + "/Images.pdf", FileMode.Create));
  doc.Open();

  doc.Add(new Paragraph("GIF"));
  Image gif;
  if (chkBoxExample.Checked)
  { 
      gif = Image.GetInstance(imagepath + "/checked.gif");
  }
  else
  {
      gif = Image.GetInstance(imagepath + "/unchecked.gif");
  }
  doc.Add(gif);
}
finally
{
  doc.Close();
}
```

Comment: Hi Gustavo, i appreciate your answer. But how can i insert the image to a placeholder in similar way we replace a placeholder with text like : (content.Replace(["Product_ID"],TextBox1.text);)

Comment: content is a variable containing all the text in the html. i am wondering if there is a way to replace a placeholder with an image by using similar method like Replace()

Comment: So you are creating an HTML document and parsing that with iTextSharp? If so, just replace your text with a standard `<img src=""/>` element and set the source to an absolute file path.